# Kubernetes - How to set DNS Policy at Cluster Level

Tags: kubernetes, dns, cluster-computing, resolution, kubernetes-pod

I am currently setting the 'dnsPolicy' configuration in the pod spec to 'Default' so that the pod can inherit the node's DNS configuration.

While this is good, it requires a re-build/re-deploy of the Docker container in order for the policy to effect and it is limited at the pod level.

Is there a similar policy that can be applied cluster-wide? Such that deployment of new pods onto the cluster will automatically inherit the nodes DNS configuration because of the cluster-wide policy?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a supported way to do this cluster-wide. One reason is that your `coredns` or `kube-dns` use `dnsPolicy: Default` and not the default `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst` so changing it cluster-wide might affect your `coredns/kube-dns` pods.

There is, however a more complicated approach that you can use with [Dynamic Admission Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/). In particular, using a [MutatingAdmissionWebhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook) that you can use to modify the pods with certain annotations to have `dnsPolicy: Default`. For example, [Istio](https://istio.io/) uses this to inject the Envoy sidecar. This is a good [document](https://medium.com/ibm-cloud/diving-into-kubernetes-mutatingadmissionwebhook-6ef3c5695f74) that describes how to build your own MutatingAdmissionWebhook.

Similar question: https://serverfault.com/questions/928257/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-default-dnspolicy-without-modifying-every-podspec